# Proof of Weyl's expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Has anybody seen a proof of [Weyl's expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_expansion)
$$
\frac{e^{-i \omega R}}{R}=\frac{1}{2 i \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \,\mathrm{d} k_x \,\mathrm{d}  k_y e^{- i (k_x x+ k_y y)} \frac{e^{-i \sqrt{\omega^2-k^2}|z|}}{\sqrt{\omega^2-k^2}}
$$

based on contour integration of the r.h.s. (and not based on a clever change of variables as in Weyl's original 1919 proof)? Above, $R=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $k=\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}$ and the square root is the square root with negative
imaginary part.

Comment: [The very first google result I had](https://engineering.purdue.edu/wcchew/ece604f19/Lecture%20Notes/Lect35.pdf) (linked in prior text) does this via residues and uniqueness of the solution of a PDE...

Comment: Yes, I know this proof which relies on the uniqueness of solutions to the PDE. I am curious about a direct calculation of the r.h.s. using contour integration.